# How to convert from String to Decimal in Visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The form has 2 list boxes, one for entering shirt sizes and price, and the other one to show the original price, after clicking on  a button, the second list box exchanges the original prices to the discounted price ( Only for prices greater than 100) its a 10% discount. This part of the code Gives me an error " Cant convert from string to decimal " 
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        getdiscountedprice(decprice)
        Decimal.TryParse(ListBox2.Items(i), decprice)

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strShirt As String
    Dim strprice As String


    Dim blnmore As Boolean = True
    Do While blnmore
        strShirt = InputBox("Enter shirt: ")
        strprice = InputBox(" Enter shirt price: ")
        If strShirt = String.Empty Or strprice = String.Empty Then
            blnmore = False
        End If

        ListBox1.Items.Add(strShirt & " " & strprice)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(strprice)
    Loop
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim decprice As Decimal


    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        getdiscountedprice(decprice)
        Decimal.TryParse(ListBox2.Items(i), decprice)

    Next
End Sub
Private Function getdiscountedprice(ByVal Fstrprice As Integer) As Decimal 'cause decimal will be returned 
    Dim lastprice As Decimal

    If Fstrprice > 100 Then
        lastprice = Fstrprice * 0.9
    End If
    Return (lastprice)

End Function

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Decimal.TryParse`  Your title does not match your variable or your error.

Comment: @LarsTech what do you mean?

Comment: String to Integer?  Your image is showing decimal, not an integer.  Don't post images of code or exceptions, we want the text posted in the question.

Comment: Please read [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @LarsTech Question added, please check it

Comment: Your are looping through the items in the ListBox, but not doing anything with the information.

Comment: Also, in your edit, you lost your question:  It's not clear anymore what your are asking.

Comment: @LarsTech So how do I fix not doing anything with the information?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn the basics of using the site

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the value from a String to a Decimal.
You can use the type conversion function CDec

```
decprice = CDec(ListBox2.Items(i).ToString)
```

or the TryParse method for Decimal

```
Decimal.TryParse(ListBox2.Items(i).ToString, decprice)
```

You have a few issues with your program that need to be resolved.
One problem with your program is in the Do While loop within your Button1_Click Sub.
If one of the strings either strShirt or strPrice is empty you are setting blnmore to False so that the loop doesn't get executed again, but you are still adding the string values to the list boxes whether they were empty or not.
You should change your code to the strings to your list boxes only when they have values:

```
If strShirt = String.Empty OrElse strprice = String.Empty Then
    blnmore = False
Else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(strShirt & " " & strprice)
    ListBox2.Items.Add(strprice)
End If
```

Also your getdiscountedprice function is expecting an Integer and you are passing it a Decimal. The function is returning a Decimal and you are not doing anything with that return value such as saving it or printing it.
You should be converting the listbox value to Decimal before calling getdiscountedprice, not after.
TryParse returns a Boolean indicating if it was successful, you probably only want to call getdiscounted price when you have a valid Decimal value.

```
If Decimal.TryParse(ListBox2.Items(i).ToString, decprice) Then
   getdiscountedprice(decprice)
End If
```

Comment: decprice = CDec(ListBox2.Items(i)) - This still gives me the same error

Comment: Decimal.TryParse(ListBox2.Items(i), decprice) - And this makes the button unfunctional

Comment: Looking at your error, it says Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid. 
The problem is you're trying to convert an empty string to a Decimal, that will cause an error with CDec and return False with TryParse indicating it was unable to parse the String.

Comment: @MarFin You should read the [documentation for Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @phaon I added the question, please check it

Answer (score 0):

You put a type object in param and convert to decimal.

```
    Public Shared Function ConvertToDecimal(ByVal p_obj As Object, Optional ByVal p_isForUi As Boolean = False) As Decimal
    Dim dRet As Decimal

    If ((p_obj Is DBNull.Value) OrElse (p_obj Is Nothing)) Then
        dRet = Decimal.MinValue
    Else
        If (p_isForUi) Then
            Dim bParseOk As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(p_obj.ToString(), dRet)
        Else
            Try
                dRet = CDec(p_obj)
            Catch exc As Exception
                dRet = Decimal.MinValue
            End Try
        End If
    End If

    Return dRet
```